# How do I notify a poise service

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Ordinarily, one would notify a service to restart by using `notifies` syntax. For example:

```
template "#{target_dir}/log4j.properties" do
  source 'log4j.properties.erb'
  owner config['user']
  group config['group']
  mode 0644
  variables(
    config: config
  )
  notifies :restart, 'service[myservice]'
end
```

But I don't think this approach works with Poise. I can't find a good example that I can get the answer to my question from, nor is it explicit in the manual.

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`notifies :restart, 'poise_service[myservice]'` :)